# TO_DATE function in ORACLE

Tags: oracle, date

I was trying the `TO_DATE` function. Specifically, I noted that the following queries

```
1. SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01-01-2015','DD-MM-YYYY'),'DD-MON-YY') FROM DUAL
2. SELECT TO_DATE('01-01-2015','DD-MM-YYYY') FROM DUAL
```

have the same output: `01-JAN-2015`.

Why does the `TO_DATE` function return the month in its abbreviated form?
My expected output for the second query is something like `01-01-2015` (simply, a TYPE conversion, NOT a format conversion).

Am I wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Please read about NLS settings. What is displayed is property of session not physical representation of date.

Comment: @Kacper So, the proper way to convert a date with a numerical month to a date with a string month is the first one?

Comment: Date is date it has neither numerical nor string month. It is only NLS setting how date is printed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dates do not have a format - they are represented by [7- or 8-bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13568348/1509264).

```
SELECT DUMP( SYSDATE ) FROM DUAL;
```

Might output:

```
Typ=13 Len=8: 220,7,11,26,16,41,9,0
```

This format is very useful for computers to compare dates but not so useful to people; so, when the SQL client (SQL/plus, SQL Developers, TOAD, etc) displays a date it does not display the the bytes but displays it as a string.

It does this by making an implicit call to `TO_CHAR()` (or some other internal method of stringifying dates) and uses a default format mask to perform this conversion.

SQL/Plus and SQL Developer will use the user's session parameter `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` to perform this conversion - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38547559/1509264) regarding this.

So your second query is implicitly being converted to do something approaching this (but, almost certainly, more efficiently):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_DATE('01-01-2015','DD-MM-YYYY'),
         ( SELECT VALUE FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT' )
       )
FROM   DUAL
```

Answer (score 2):

The default **output format** of `DATE` value, resp `TO_DATE()` function is set by `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` value. You can verify it with this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS 
WHERE PARAMETER = NLS_DATE_FORMAT';
```

You can change it on session level for example with

```
alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MM-YYYY';
```

Answer (score 0):

The output format of TO_CHAR is not correct, try:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01-01-2015','DD-MM-YYYY'),'DD-MM-YYYY') FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Oracle TO_DATE](https://www.oraask.com/wiki/oracle-to-date): is used to convert a character string to a date format.

and related to your concern; you need to alter your session like below:

```
alter session set nls_date_format='DD-MM-YYYY'
```

in your apps right after the connect.

So now if you run again your query :

```
SELECT TO_DATE ('01-01-2015', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
FROM DUAL;
```

the result would be as expected:

> 01-01-2015

Hope that will help.